# N+1 parallel threads accessing the same queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I am writing a code with `N+1> (=6)`  parallel threads accessing the same queue. The threads start all at the same time but terminate based on different conditions. The first N on a timer, the last one on a counter (I'll explain below).
The first 5 threads generate messages consisting of 6 bytes `[ID, progressive_nr, 4bytes]`. The last 4 bytes are 4 identical chars (ex `'AAAA'`, `'BBBB'`,...). There `N` threads just push the messages into a shared queue, each with its own frequency and for a certain duration. After 'duration' has elapsed for `i-th` thread, I want that `i-th` thread to end.
The 6th thread should continuously monitor the queue and whenever there is a message pop it and after releasing the queue (as quickly as possible) do some processing and print the retrieved message.

I have two problems: 1. I get stuck at the end of the first N threads and it seems like they do not terminate them. 2. I am not sure how to implement the 6th thread, how to "monitor" the queue to see if there are messages still allowing other threads to push in messages, and how to terminate it on a specific condition, for example after it has popped 1000 messages from the queue.
Here is the code for the first part, in the `main` I never get to the last `while` to print the elements of the queue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <cstring>
#include <mutex>

const int N = 5;
const int IDs[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
const int startDelays[N] = { 0, 2, 3, 4, 1 };
const int durations[N] = { 1, 3, 2, 1, 3 };
const int timePeriods[N] = { 100, 110, 220, 150, 250 };
const int percentageError = 10; // Percentage of error injected

 // Define a struct to hold thread-specific parameters
struct ThreadParams {
uint8_t id;
int startDelay;
int duration;
int timePeriod;
char replicationChar;
};

std::queue<std::string> messageQueue;
std::mutex queueMutex;

bool terminateThreads = false;

void threadFunction(const ThreadParams& params) {
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(params.startDelay));
std::cout << "Thread " << static_cast<char>('A' + params.id) << " started." <<std::endl;

int messageNumber = 0;
auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

while (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() 
- startTime).count() < params.duration) {
    if (terminateThreads) {
        break;
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(params.timePeriod));

    char idChar = static_cast<char>('A' + params.id);
    char progressiveChar = static_cast<char>('0' + messageNumber);

    std::string message;
    message.push_back(static_cast<char>(params.id) + '0');
    message.push_back(progressiveChar);
    message.append(4, params.replicationChar);

    if (!terminateThreads && params.id != N) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queueMutex);
            messageQueue.push(message);
        }

        std::cout << "Thread " << static_cast<char>('A' + params.id) << " added message: 
 " << message << std::endl;
    }

    ++messageNumber;
}

if (!terminateThreads && params.id != N) {
    std::string xMessage;
    xMessage.push_back(static_cast<char>(params.id) + '0');
    xMessage.append(5, 'X');

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queueMutex);
        messageQueue.push(xMessage);
    }

    std::cout << "Thread " << static_cast<char>('A' + params.id) << " added X message: " 
<< xMessage << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "Thread " << static_cast<char>('A' + params.id) << " ended." << std::endl;
}




int main() {
std::thread threads[N + 1];
ThreadParams threadParams[N + 1];

for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
    threadParams[i].id = static_cast<uint8_t>(i);
    threadParams[i].startDelay = startDelays[i];
    threadParams[i].duration = durations[i];
    threadParams[i].timePeriod = timePeriods[i];
    threadParams[i].replicationChar = static_cast<char>('A' + i);

    threads[i] = std::thread(threadFunction, threadParams[i]);
}

// Allow threads to run for their specified durations
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(*std::max_element(durations, durations 
+ N + 1)));

// Signal threads to terminate
terminateThreads = true;

/*   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    threads[i].join();
}*/
std::cout << "Message in queue: " << std::endl;

while (!messageQueue.empty()) {
    std::cout << "Message in queue: " << messageQueue.front() << std::endl;
    messageQueue.pop();
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "typical" way to manage a thread pool is that whenever a thread pulls something off the queue, that thread is marked as "processing", and the queue is not empty until there are both: 1) no more tasks to do; 2) no threads still processing a task.

Comment: "std::this_thread::sleep_for" - there's a problem, right there.. A sleep is never the right solution.

Comment: It looks like you have a race condition on `terminateThreads`. Even fundamental types like `bool` need to be synchronized. Edit : removed failed copy/paste

Comment: @JesperJuhl what do you suggest instead of sleep to implement a periodic generation of messages?

Comment: Have you tried the approach with communicating external events using `condition_variable` ? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: There is an issue in your `std::this_thread::sleep_for`.

You're only considering the `duration` parameter, but you also need to consider `startDelay`. 

You're current code doesn't allow D thread to execute, it's immediately ended because you start it with : `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(params.startDelay));`.

Changing your main sleep to : `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(*std::max_element(durations, durations + N)) + std::chrono::seconds(*std::max_element(startDelays, startDelays + N)));` 

Makes it work better and D thread has time to finish.